# Is it possible to determine max external monitors and resolution from graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution

Is it possible to determine the maximum number and resolution of external monitors from the graphics card of a laptop?

For example, both the 2018 Macbook Pro and 2018 Surface Pro i7 have the Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640.

According to Apple, the Macbook Pro:

> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display
>   in millions of colours and: [...] Up to two displays with 3840-by-2160
>   resolution at 60Hz in over a billion colour

Does this mean that the Surface Pro does as well?
(The Surface Pro inbuilt display has slightly lower resolution)

Answer (score 1):

Run from console(cmd) on Surface following code:

```
wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight,screenwidth
```

to get number of monitors and resolutions that will be supported.

P.S.
This code won't reveal monitors that hooked to USB docking station(s) but only monitors connected to internal graphic cards.